# What's the correct way to merge the code into one loop?

Tags: scala

This is my origin code, I would like to merge them into one loop

```
//1
if (eventUuidList.nonEmpty) {
  eventUuidTransactionTableCondition = for {
    eventUuid <- eventUuidList
    eventUuidTransactionTableConditionSet =
      s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_UUID} = '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'")
  } yield eventUuidTransactionTableConditionSet
  eventUuidTransactionTableConditionSet = "and ".concat(eventUuidTransactionTableCondition.reduce(_.concat(" or ").concat(_)))
}
//2
if (eventUuidList.nonEmpty) {
  eventUuidExceptionTableCondition = for {
    eventUuid <- eventUuidList
    eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet =
      s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_UUID} != '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'")
  } yield eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet
  eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet = "and ".concat(eventUuidExceptionTableCondition.reduce(_.concat(" and ").concat(_)))
}
```

The different for these two parts are those lines (the first has `=` and the second `!=`):

```
//1
s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_UUID} = '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'")
eventUuidTransactionTableConditionSet = "and ".concat(eventUuidTransactionTableCondition.reduce(_.concat(" or ").concat(_)))
//2
s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_UUID} != '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'")
eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet = "and ".concat(eventUuidExceptionTableCondition.reduce(_.concat(" and ").concat(_)))
```

I moved both parts into the same block. Is what I have below the correct way to do that? Or there is a better solution?

```
var eventUuidTransactionTableConditionSet, eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet  = " "

if (eventUuidList.nonEmpty) {
  val both = eventUuidList.map( eventUuid =>
              s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_UUID} = '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'") ->
              s"${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_INFO_STRUCT_NAME}.${SQLColumnHelper.EVENT_UUID} != '".concat(eventUuid).concat("'"))

  val (eventUuidTransactionTableCondition, eventUuidExceptionTableCondition) = both.unzip

  eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet = "and ".concat(eventUuidTransactionTableCondition.mkString(" or "))
  eventUuidExceptionTableConditionSet = "and ".concat(eventUuidExceptionTableCondition.mkString(" and "))
}
```

Comment: Why not iterate over a `Seq` containing those two strings?

Comment: @user, Hi, could you please provide more detail, I'm new to Scala..

Comment: Something like `Seq("=", "!=").foreach{c => if (eventUuidList.nonEmpty{...s"blahblah $c '".concat...}}`

Comment: By the way, is the third/last snippet (right below "Or there is a better solution?") different from the first snippet? If so, could you make it clear what you changed there?

Comment: The third snippet is what I did to merge them together

Comment: Oh, I see, they're both inside the if statement. Let me just make that clear (feel free to roll back my edit if you don't like it)

Comment: That's totally fine, and I try what you said, I think I didn't get the correct result..Could you please show me more complete code..Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with this code it's hard to know where to begin. But to your question...

Why not create a tuple of the 2 string interpolations and then unzip them?

```
val both = eventUuidList.map(id => s"blahblah = '${id}'" ->
                                   s"blahblah != '${id}'")

val (eventUuidTransactionTableCondition
    ,eventUuidExceptionTableCondition) = both.unzip
```

Comment: Can you let me know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: 1-Why test for list `.nonEmpty`? A `for` comprehension on an empty `List` returns an empty `List`. Essentially a no-op. 2-The code appears to use many `var`s. Bad, bad, bad. 3-Why use `.concat()` when you are already using the more convenient string interpolation? 4-Replace the `.reduce()` with `.mkString(" or ")`. 5-Why create a variable and then `yield` it? Just `yield` the interpolated `String` directly. 6-Why not create a tuple of the 2 string interpolations and then `.unzip` them?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I modified my code

Comment: Thank you so much!